# Why would saving files in the Developer Console in a sandbox take a long time?

Tags: apex, developer-console

I'm using Developer Console in a development sandbox for the first time. When I try to save some code I've edited, it takes *forever* to save. In fact I don't even know if the save ever finishes, as I hit save about 30 minutes ago and the tab still says "Saving".

I thought that one of the benefits of developing the sandbox was that all unit tests are run on save, only when deploying to production. If that's the case, why would my save be taking so long?

Comment: That doesn't sound right (like it shouldn't be taking that long to save). What happens if you edit the class out of the developer console? E.g. App Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Edit Action

Comment: Yeah, so what's happened since I posted this question: I closed the Developer Console despite it warning me that I would lose my changes. When I came back in, all my tabs were there just as I had left them AND my changes were saved. So it looks like the interface sometimes just doesn't get the message that the save has finished and therefore it never updates. Yes, when I try to edit the class out of the developer console I also see the changes have been saved. I'll add this also happens when running tests sometimes. It just sits there spinning as if it's still running when it's actually done.

Comment: I'd suspect an underlying error in the developer console. Maybe check the browsers console for Javascript errors when it stops working. Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 38.0.2125.104 on Mac OS X Mavericks. I will check the browser console the next time it happens. Is this the world we live in where the SFDC authored tool doesn't work?

Comment: Like all software, there are times where the developer console breaks. Hopefully these occurrences are few and far between. YMMV. There are alternatives like the Force.com IDE and Mavens Mate. They all get errors at some point or another.

Comment: I've had my JS console open for the last couple of hours to see what's going on with it. It works fine for a while and then eventually for some reason it errors out saying: Error connecting Streaming API {"channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"<redacted>","advice":{"reconnect":"handshake","interval":500},"error":"403::Unknown client","successful":false,"id":"6"}. Works fine and then just loses the connection. Perhaps this is something for SFDC support, though I've never filed a support ticket for dev issues so I'm not sure if that process leads me to someone competent in these matters.

Comment: The Streaming API uses the Bayeux protocol and CometD to do long polling against the server. If the connection is interrupted or the session expires it may not reset correctly. I'm not sure what the official timeout period is for the Developer Console. Personally I use Sublime Text and Mavens Mate for most development. I find the Developer Console is more useful for smaller tasks than as a day-to-day IDE.